# Populate table with MVC on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC by converting an old Web Form to MVC 5. The page is pretty simple, just a few text boxes, a submit button and a grid. I want similar functionality where there is no grid on page load, and after the submit takes place, the grid appears. The issue I am having is all the examples I have seen contain the data coming at page load.

Here is my View

```
<h2>Search Craigslist</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Enter Search Criteria:<br />

        @Html.TextBox("Criteria", null, new { @style = "width: 450" })

        @Html.DropDownList("DropDownValues")
        Days:
        @Html.TextBox("Days")
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </p>

}
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_Search.cshtml")
```

and the partial

```
@model IEnumerable<CraigsListSearch.MVC.Models.SearchModel>
@{
Layout = null;
}


<table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
    </th>
    <th>
        Link
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateSubmitted)
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Hyperlink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.URL).ToString(), Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title).ToString())
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateSubmitted)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and finally the controller

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    //public ViewResult Index(string DropDownValues, string Criteria, string Days)
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        Populate();

        Session["list"] = SearchModel.GetQuickList();
        return View(new List<SearchModel>());

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(string DropDownValues, string Criteria, string Days)
    {
        Populate();
        Criteria = Server.UrlPathEncode(Criteria).Replace(",", "%2c");

        List<Location> list = (List<Location>)(Session["list"]);
        List<SearchModel> results = SearchModel.Search(Criteria, Days, DropDownValues, list.Take(5).ToList());
        return View(results);
    }

    private void Populate()
    {
        List<DropDownModel> ddlList = DropDownModel.GetDropdowns();

        ViewBag.DropDownValues = (from a in ddlList
                                  select new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Text = a.Text,
                                      Value = a.Value
                                  }).ToList();
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is to have the partial only be "called" on POST. Is this something that can easily be done? Let me know if other info is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach solving this problem.

One option would be to use AJAX. When the user clicks the button make an AJAX call to the controller and have the controller render the partial and return the HTML which you then inject into the page DOM.

Another option is to add a "DisplayGrid" property to your model. When you first render the View set it to false and then set it to true after the post.

One point I want to make is that rendering a View from the Post action isn't a great idea. If the user hits Refresh in their browser it's going to post again, giving the user that annoyingly ugly dialog that tells them they're going to send data to the server. In general you should use a Post-Redirect-Get pattern, the user posts, you redirect, and then you use a get to re-render in the browser. If you use the AJAX approach this all becomes moot because you never post the whole form back to a controller action. If you continue to use a full post the HttpPost version of Index should return a RedirectToAction result sending the user back to the Get version of Index. You can communicate between the two actions by using TempData, for example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if( TempData.ContainsKey( "DisplayGrid" )
    {
        // Use the other values from TempData to populate the model with the grid data
        myModel.DisplayGrid = (bool)TempData["DisplayGrid"];
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index( string dropDownValues, string criteria, string days )
{
    TempData["DisplayGrid"] = true;
    TempData["DropDownValues"] = dropDownValues;
    TempData["Criteria"] = criteria;
    TempData["Days"] = days;

    return RedirectToAction( "Index" );
}
```

Comment: so it makes sense to Ajax the call then, because I have read not to use TempData.

Comment: I don't know where you would have read such ridiculous advice. Microsoft created TempData for a reason so to make a blanket statement that you shouldn't use TempData is irresponsible and uninformed.

Comment: So you can put the whole object in TempData and read from it like Session?

Comment: You could. Personally I'd probably just put the boolean and the criteria itself into TempData and then do the retrieval in the HttpGet version of Index, mainly just to keep what gets stuffed into TempData a little more lightweight.

Comment: Thank you much, I got it up and running pretty quick with this!

Comment: Actually one quick thing. What is the best way to persist the values in the text boxes on the redirect? Are we still looking at TempData and populate, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: The only way to keep values between the redirect is TempData. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass whatever information you need to render view via model (or `ViewBag`).

Since you already have sample of how to use `Model` here is how you can use `ViewBag`

```
@if(ViewBag.RenderSearch)
{
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_Search.cshtml")
}
```

And set `RenderSearch` in particular action:

```
public ViewResult Index(string DropDownValues...
{
     ....
     ViewBag.RenderSearch = true;
```

With model just add property to your model (you'd need to make it custom class instead of just `List`) and check that flag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, the Ajax only replace the GridDiv only

```
<h2>Search Craigslist</h2>

using (Ajax.BeginForm("BindGridAction", "Contoller",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "GridDiv" }))
{
    <p>
        Enter Search Criteria:<br />

        @Html.TextBox("Criteria", null, new { @style = "width: 450" })

        @Html.DropDownList("DropDownValues")
        Days:
        @Html.TextBox("Days")
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </p>

    }
<div id="GridDiv">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_Search.cshtml")
</div>
```

Bind your partial view in controller

```
    public PartialViewResult BindGridAction()
    {
       // your model coding
        return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_Search.cshtml", model);
    }
```